# Convert UserCollection to FieldUserValue[] inside my CSOM code

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I have the following CSOM code:-

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Group group = context.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName(webname);
FieldUserValue[] values = null;
```

now i want to add all the users inside the `group` to the `FieldUserValue[]`, but i am not sure how i can convert the `User` to `FieldUSerValue`?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the below code :

```
$userName = “domain\username”
 $spuser = EnsureUser $context      $userName
$lookupValue = @() 
if($spuser -ne $null){ 
$spuserValue = New-Object   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue
 $spuserValue.LookupId =   $spuser.id 
 $lookupValue += $spuserValue
   }
  $userValue =      [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue[]]$lookupValue 
 $listItem[“Your People Picker   FieldColumn name”] = $userValue
  $listItem.Update()
```

Source :

[How to Set People Picker value in SharePoint using CSOM and Powershell?](http://www.letsharepoint.com/how-to-set-people-picker-value-in-sharepoint-using-csom-and-powershell/)

[SharePoint Online: Read / Update Person or Group Field (People Picker) Values using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/10/sharepoint-online-get-set-person-or-group-people-picker-field-using-powershell.html?m=1)